# How to modify a built-in functions like nn.MSECriterion.lua in torch

Tags: neural-network, torch, mse

I have modified the file nn/lib/THNN/generic/MSECriterion.c in torch such that XxX is changed to XxX/2. But on calling the function nn.MSECriterion(vector1, vector2), it is executing the same old function XxX. How can I execute the change newly incorporated. Is it even possible to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to recompile them.

Comment: Thanks Chen. I tried recompiling using cd torch/extra/nn/;
luarocks make rocks/nn-scm-1.rockspec. But it is not working.